# In Magic: The Gathering, how does Ugin, the Ineffable's static ability interact with colorless spells that have X in their cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Ugin, the Ineffable](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUgin%2c%20the%20Ineffable%5d) in play and I want to cast [Ugin's Conjurant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUgin%27s%5d%2b%5bConjurant%5d), how does Ugin, the Ineffable's static ability interact with paying the cost?

Can I announce I want to cast Ugin's Conjurant for 5 and then only pay 3 mana because Ugin, the Ineffable's static abilit reads "Colorless spells you cast cost 2 less to cast"?

Comment: @Hackworth Oh shoot, good spot! I thought we might've had something like this before, but couldn't find it. I'm going to roll back my genericisation of the title so that people searching on this speific issue can find that generic dupe target.

Comment: Apologies for the duplication. Have upvoted your answer in the original question as well.

Comment: No worries. I remember such old dupes only if I answered them myself .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can choose 5 for X then only pay 3 mana with Ugin, the Ineffable out.

This is because [the process of casting a spell](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr601/) works like this:

1. Make choices your spell offers you, including choosing modes and the value you'll pay for X in the casting cost where applicable.
2. Choose targets.
3. Determine the total cost of the spell, which is its cost plus any cost increases and minus any cost reductions.
4. Pay that cost.

(There's some other details I've glossed over, but those are the most commonly encountered parts.)

This means in step 1, you're choosing 5 as the value for {X}. Then in step 3, you determine the cost: that's {5} reduced by {2} to get a total cost of {3}.

This also means if you chose 2 as the value for X, you may cast Ugin's Conjurant for {0}.